# What is the difference between two sentence in meaning?

Tags: grammar

1. I have three sons who became a doctor.
2. I have three sons,who became a doctor.

   I want to know the difference between two sentences.
   Please, tell me the difference in meaning.

Comment: There is a number mismatch in both. If all three are doctors then you should use "who became doctors", not "a doctor".

Comment: Sometimes adding a comma can change the meaning of a sentence. That doesn't seem to be the case here, though.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are incorrect grammatically; you are referring to a plural noun 'sons' that must take the plural noun  i.e. dictors.  So the correct sentences are:

I have three sons who became doctors.

I have three sons, who became doctors.

As for the difference between these sentences, the clause without a comma before the relative clause "who became doctors" is a defining relative clause in the former sentence. It means that you have more than three doctors. Out of them, three became doctors.

The clause with a comma before the relative clause is a non defining relative clause. It indicates that you have only three sons; they all became doctors.