# Does a comma make any difference in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

> 1. I have three daughters who became nurses.
> 2. I have three daughters, who became nurses.

I got the answers from [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88763/what-is-the-difference-between-two-sentence-in-meaning) before but some says that the comma makes some differences, others says that there is no difference. Please, tell me the difference in meaning when the comma is added.

Comment: The comma is a token typographic reflection of differences in phrasal contour and syntactic pause which would disambiguate between restrictive and non-restrictive clause  in a *spoken* context.

Answer (score 3):

There is the difference between the two sentences. The first is the restrictive attributive clause which means you have three daughters becoming nurses and actually you have other daughters except the three. The second sentence is nonrestrictive attributive clause which means you only have three daughters and all of them have become nurses.